# find the smallest number in a text file (python)

Tags: python, file, text, numbers

So I have a text file with roughly 400 lines, each line has a number and I need to find the smallest of these numbers.

I currently have

```
def smallestnumber(fread, fwrite):
number = {int(line) for line in fread}
smallest = min(number)
print ("smallest number is", smallest)
```

But it doesnt work for some reason. What would be the best way to get the smallest number in the .txt file? (fread is the .txt file that I have opened in main() function! And I will write the number to fwrite, once I manage to figure it out lol)

EDIT: I get an error (ValueError) at the smallest = min(number) part saying "min() arg is an empty sequence".

EDIT2: I am using a test.txt file to test the code first before, and its just

1000
700
450
200
100
10
1
on different lines each
So the same format/type as the file I am supposed to use

fread (where I get the numbers) and fwrite (where i want to save the numbers) are defined as follows in main()

```
name= input("Give the name of the file which to take data from: ")
fread = open(name, "r") #File which is being read
name2= input("Give the name of the file where to save to: ")
fwrite = open(name2, "w") #File which is being typed to
```

I'm sorry for possible bad "formating" etc of this question, I am new to python and StackOverflow!

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Edit the question to explain "doesn't work", what happens?

Comment: what else does the line contain?

Comment: The error means that the set number is empty, can you show us what fread is?

Comment: The error you have received says that you have no elements in `number`. The only way this would be is if `fread` produces no values, for example if it is a handle to an empty file, or it is an empty list, or an empty string, or such. As kinshukdua says, show us how `fread` is defined.

Comment: Can you show part of your txt file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
def smallestnumber(fread, fwrite):
    # store the numbers in a list
    numbers = [int(line) for line in fread]
    # sort the list so that the smallest number is the first element of the list
    numbers.sort()
    # print the first element of the list which contains the smallest number 
    print ("smallest number is: {0}".format(numbers[0])
```

I did not run the code, but it should work. It would be best if you had more error-checking. For example, `int(line)` could throw an exception if `line` is not a number.

Your code does not work because list comprehensions should use square brackets instead of curly brackets.

It should be `[int(line) for line in fread]` and not `{int(line) for line in fread}`

Once you have a list the function `min` also will work.

Comment: For some reason it still doesnt work.  I changed the brackets from {} -> [] but it still says that min() arg is an empty sentence :/

Comment: if it says that `arg is an empty sequence` it means you are not reading the file properly and the list inside the function `min` is empty.

Comment: That's weird. I have the same fread being used in a different function that calculates the total sum of the numbers and I got it to work just fine.  The fread is attached to handle called "file" and I used file = (name, "r") to open it at the beginning main()

Comment: Then it means that you already read to the end of the file in your previous function.
add `fread.seek(0)` before `numbers = [int(line) for line in fread]` to go back at the beginning of the file.

Comment: it works!! Thank you so much @andrea ! You saved my mental health and possibly my software course grade! <3

Answer (score 0):

```
max=-9999
for line in open('lines.txt').readlines():
  #print(line)
  for word in line.split():
    #print(word,word.isnumeric())
    if word.isnumeric() and int(word)>max:
      max=int(word)
print(max)
```